# How to insert character before match pattern using vim or sed?

Tags: vim, sed

```
int main () {
  int a = 1;
}
```

change to

```
#int main() {
  #int a = 1;
#}
```

How to insert '#' before each line?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort. [sed insert character at first position of each line site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=sed+insert+character+at+first+position+of+each+line+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: whats the pattern here? before which lines? there are multiple ways of doing that, a regex is not always the best of them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to put a comment marker following the (possibly empty) white space at the start of each line, you can just use a capture group to get it as per the following transcript:

```
printf "int main () {\n    int a = 1;\n}\n" | sed 's/^\(\s*\)/\1#/'
#int main () {
    #int a = 1;
#}
```

In more detail:

```
  a  ccc   dd    <- markers, see below.
s/^\(\s*\)/\1#/
   bb   bb   e   <- markers, see below.
```

- Marker `a`, the `^` character, is the start line anchor, meaning this will only operate at the start of each line.
- Marker `b`, the `\(...\)` set, is a capture group, meaning that whatever text is captured by this pattern will be stored for later use.
- Marker `c`, which is the `\s*` will match zero or more white space character. The fact that this is inside the capture group means it will be stored.
- Marker `d` is the first capture group `\1` specified earlier. This will simply insert what was captured into the replacement string. The numbers to use for capture groups can be complex, especially if you capture in hierarchies. But, since you only capture *one* thing here, it's fairly simple.
- Marker `e` is simply the `#` that you want to add to the end of your captured text.

The bottom line is that it finds the largest white-space section at the start of each line and appends the `#` character to it.

---

As [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) points out in a comment, you can also use:

```
sed 's/[^ \t]/#&/'
```

which will insert `#` before the first non-space-non-tab character on each line.

Comment: Another variant with sed and only white spaces: `sed 's/[^ ]/#&/' file`

Comment: @Cyrus, that *is* simpler. I can't get it running with general whitespace rather thand a space character - `s/[^\s]/#&/` seems to always insert before the *first* character on the line rather than the first non-whitespace one. However, `[^<space><tab>]` *does seem to work so I'll incoprorate it.

Comment: @paxdiablo that's because tools like sed/grep/awk etc do not support backslash sequences inside a character class.. you can use named character classes instead, like `[:space:]`

Comment: or, use `\S` if it is supported, like the GNU versions of these tools

Comment: @Sundeep: Thank you for this hint. This works for me with GNU sed: `sed 's/[^[:space:]]/#&/' file`

Comment: For completeness, since the question asked about Vim too, one solution very similar to @Cyrus is `:%s/\S/#&`. But you can also do it with Vim commands, like `:%norm I#`. Alternatively, if you have Perl support, `:%perldo s/\s*\K/#/` which shows yet another regex solution using `\K`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
:%s/\(^.*$\)/#\1/g
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```
:%norm! _i#

% ......... hole file
nomrm! .... normal mode
_ ......... first non-blank of the line
i# ........ insert comment
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible vim approach using block edit

```
ggctrl-vGI#esc
```

Start with `gg` followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> , then `GI`. Now press the character you want to insert, `#` and finalize it with <kbd>esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In vim:
First make sure you are not in insert mode by hitting the escape key.
Then hit the colon key and enter:

1,3s/^[ \t]*/&#/

This says from lines 1 through 3, after the beginning of the line and some possible
spaces and/or tabs, repeat those possible spaces and/or tabs and append a hash
symbol.